# Is there a situation where you can say "Il est plus grand que je" instead of "que moi"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-personnels, comparatifs

I'm thinking in English: He is taller than I vs. He is taller than me.
Now, in French: "Il est plus grand que je (suis)" instead of "que moi"?

Answer (score 3):

Not in that sense.  In French, tonic or stress pronouns are used even with the verb être.  *C'est moi* always, never *c'est* **je.*

Il est plus grand que moi.

Or

Il est plus grand que je ne le suis.

Notice how you would need to complete the second sentence giving je a verb.  It cannot end with *que* **je*.

Other instances when you can use que je include comparisons between two subjects (examples from Lawless French):

> J’ai plus d’idées que toi.        I have more ideas than you.

> Tu fais moins
> d’erreurs que moi.
> You make fewer errors than I (do).

> Elle a écrit
> autant de livres que son père.        She’s written as many books as her father.

The second example highlights the English grammar of your thinking.

Furthermore, to give a complete answer to the frame of the question, if the verbs are different, you could also complete that sentence using que je + verb.  It would not mean the same thing.

Il est plus grand que je ne pensais.

Some examples from [Lawless French](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/comparative-adverbs/):

> Compare two verbs
>
> Je lis plus que je ne regarde la télé.        I read more than I watch TV.
>
> Anne chante autant qu’elle parle.      Anne sings as much as she speaks.
>
> The subject must be repeated in front of the second verb.
>
> Ne explétif is required with plus and moins.

Comment: Even with the same verb, you can say "Il est plus grand que je ne le suis".